# Set weight for JavaScript files loaded via theme.libraries.yml?

Tags: theming, 8

Im loading a JavaScript file via my theme's libraries.yml file. How can I change the weight of this file?

I need the file to load before the core and module's JavaScript files. If I set `header: true` then this happens, but I still want to load the file at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to try this with in libraries.yml file

```
js:
    js/foo.js:
    js/bar.js: { weight: N }
```

Comment: Note the the value must be in quotes.

Comment: no need of quotes. Try without it.

Comment: UnexpectedValueException: The theme/lib library defines a positive weight for 'js/bar.js'. Only negative weights are allowed (but should be avoided). Instead of a positive weight, specify accurate dependencies for this library.