# How do I include a JS file that conditionally overrides a JS library in D8?

Tags: 8, javascript, theming

We use the [jQuery Validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) plugin as a library we declare in our *mymodule*.libraries.yml.

However, our site is multilingual, and this plugin provides localized strings in separate language-specific JS files (messages.*langcode*.min.js) that need to be evaluated after the main library is included.

If I include the language specific file in an #attached element in *mymodule*_preprocess_page(), would that cause it to be evaluated *after* the main library? If not, how should this be done?

Comment: It's controlled with `weight` (see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/202138/set-weight-for-javascript-files-loaded-via-theme-libraries-yml). It should be as simple as using a higher weight in the preprocess code than the libraries code