# How can I put custom javascript file at bottom

Tags: 8, theming

When I want to override sites/all/libraries  Example/example.js file from my custom js file but  example.js file at bottom than custom.js file the problem is not give my result of custom.js file because it is above than example.js file.

Comment: check this thread https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/202138/set-weight-for-javascript-files-loaded-via-theme-libraries-yml

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set weight for JavaScript files loaded via theme.libraries.yml?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/202138/set-weight-for-javascript-files-loaded-via-theme-libraries-yml)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your JS file to load after another js file, you could add a dependency

```
cuddly-slider:
  js:
    js/cuddly-slider.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - some_module/example
```

---

If you want to swap the JS files, load your file instead of the original one, you can accomplish that in [hook_page_attachments_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_page_attachments_alter/8.2.x).